# deserialization of json string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to deserealize values of json string which is as follows

```
{"data":[
{"description":"xxxxxx","created_time":1330356685},
    {"description":"zzzz","created_time":1329817903}
]}
```

My class is as follows:

```
public class NewFriends
{
    public Data[] data { get; set; }

    public class Data
    {
        string description { get; set; }
        int created_time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but when I am deserealizing values I am getting null values in the array indexes of nFrnds

```
NewFriends nFrnds = serializer.Deserialize<NewFriends>(newFriends);
```

Please help!

Comment: @CloseVoter, this is not too localized. Questions like this are the reason StackOverflow exists.

Comment: What serializer are you using. There are 2 built into .Net, and I assume you are attempting to use one of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me:

```
string s = "{\"data\":[{\"description\":\"xxxxxx\",\"created_time\":1330356685},    {\"description\":\"zzzz\",\"created_time\":1329817903}]}";
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
NewFriends nFrnds = jss.Deserialize(s, typeof(NewFriends)) as NewFriends;
MessageBox.Show(nFrnds.data.Length.ToString());
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to suggest that you look into using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). It will make the deserialization process a breeze.

> PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

```
public class NewFriends
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }

}

public class Data
{
     string description { get; set; }
     int created_time { get; set; }
}
```

```
var jsonObj = @"{"data":[
{"description":"xxxxxx","created_time":1330356685},
    {"description":"zzzz","created_time":1329817903}
]}"


NewFriends newFriends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewFriends>(jsonObj);
```

Comment: I didn't get the impression that he *is* writing a deserializer, only that the one he is using ins't working properly. I could be wrong.

Comment: It appears to me as though he's trying to build a POCO for the JSON object and getting hung up. Maybe traveling down the "DataContract" path... Not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

try to use a `List` instead of an `Array`

```
public class NewFriends
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }

}

public class Data
{
     string description { get; set; }
     int created_time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't like List<> when I can use arrays